# Javascript Object Array access properties undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here is some output that I get from firebug

```
<div id='div_undefined'>[{"Region":"AD","Date":"","ArticleID":"abc-345"},    {"Region":"CD","Date":"","ArticleID":"abc-345"}]</div>
```

You can see the JS Object array in there and notice the div_undefined. If you look at the funciton below I know that my object is defined because it is printing out. Why would Items[0] return undefined when I try to access ArticleID

here is the code from my function

```
function myFunc(Items){
    var item = Items[0];
    Write("<div id='div_" + item.ArticleID + "'>" + Items + "</div>");
}
```

Comment: Why would you debug like this, and not just `console.log(item)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If concatenating `Items` produces this output, then it's a **string** (containing JSON) and you have to parse it to a JS data structure first (an array in this case):

```
function myFunc(Items){
    Items = JSON.parse(Items);
    var item = Items[0];
    Write("<div id='div_" + item.ArticleID + "'>" + Items + "</div>");
    // Will output
    // <div id='div_abc-345'>[object Object], [object Object]</div>
}
```

Ideally you would do this *before* you pass the value to the function. I don't know which output you are after, so that's all I can advice.

---

Otherwise, `Items[0]` refers to the first letter of the string (a string as well) and strings don't have an `ArticleID` property, hence you get `undefined`.

---

You might find this question helpful as well: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value) And as mentioned by Matt (and in the other question), if you want to *debug* your code, use `console.log`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense as before I send the data via jQuery I do this JSON.stringify(parameterArray) so yep I have a string and not an object. Thanks for pointing that out guys.